# Strangest Python dict AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-3.6

I've gotten a JSON object from a HTTPS request as follows:

```
rurl = "some url"
dat = requests.get(rurl).json()
```

Some information relevant to the problem:

```
print(dat)
print(dat.keys())
print('chain' in dat)
```

which gives the output

```
{'chain': {'current': 0, more attributes...}}
dict_keys(['chain'])
True
```

now I try to access the object:

```
chain_data = dat['chain']
```

but it gives an error for some reason:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'chain'
```

But printing out the keys beforehand shows it clearly has this attribute, no?

Other things I tried with the same error as the result:

```
dat.get('chain')
dat[(list(dat.keys()))[0]]
```

I am running Python 3.6.4.

```
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48ecebad5, Dec 18 2017, 21:07:28) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
```

Comment: Are you able to make this into a reproducible example, without the `requests.get` part?

Comment: What is chain_data. I would expect a key error if this was a dat problem. What's also weird is your prints work, but the get doesn't, almost as if it's getting changed somehow

Comment: The error you mentioned would be produced by `dat.chain`, NOT `dat['chain']` (that would be a `KeyError` if it failed).  I don't think you're running quite the code you think you are.

Comment: @jasonharper You basically got it. What happened was that the `dat['chain']` line was not the error, but a different line of code 10 lines down that i mysteriously decided to use `dat.chain` in. And I was running this in a `discord.py` context, which doesn't tell me which line the error is in... thanks for the help!